# Map through array of objects one by one in ReactJs one by one rather than listing the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array-map

i have a react functional component

```
const Quiz = () => {
   const [Quizdata, setQuizdata] = useState([{name: 'John'},{name: 'jack'}])
 
   return (
    {Quizdata.map(quiz => {<h1>{quiz.name}</h1>)}
   )
}
```

In the above code i will get list of object but i want to display single element of Quizdata Array and i want to iterate through whole array by some next button

Comment: single element of Quizdata is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe mean something like this..?

```
const App = () => {

    const [Quizdata, setQuizdata] = useState([{name: 'John'}, {name: 'jack'}])
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)

    const handleNext = () => {
        setSelected(selected + 1)
    }

    const handlePrevious = () => {
        setSelected(selected - 1)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handlePrevious}>Previous</button>
            <button onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
            <p>{Quizdata[selected].name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```